# Jetty interrupting connection

Tags: java, stream, jetty, interrupt

I have a application that return a long request that returns a stream (a huge json)
The application is written in Java and I'm using Jetty as server.

The problem is after sometimes getting data, it stops. I made some tests and sometimes I got 10, 15, 40%.. doesn't matter.. Jetty interrupts the connection at some moment. I already isolated only one machine without other requests and it happens the same way.

I do not know how to debug, cause I didn't see any error. It only interrupts.

Any help is appreciate

Comment: Are you sire it's Jetty and not a filter? Just mentioning this as I had an issue like this long time ago with logback-access, in which a logging filter didn't return all the content from a request.

Answer (score 0):

What version of jetty?

Is this on a slow connection perhaps?
If so, you are likely encountering idle timeouts.

It can happen like this ....

- Server has a large amount of data to send, it sends until there is TCP backpressure from the client telling it "woah!".
- So the Server waits until the TCP layer says its ok to start sending again.
- The client is slow.
- This wait is longer than the configured Idle Timeout for that connector.
- The server closes the connection.

Comment: version 6.1.24-6. Not a slow connection. It is a streaming response, I mean there is no long wait to return, it starts to return little parts and the connection always keep live and I can see the content printing in a file .. until to be interrupted. I am doing random tests with different configurations... Thanks.